# Range from n in both directions

Tags: javascript

Given `let n = 9`, I want to return `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`. I know I can write it like so:

```
const up = [...Array(4).keys()].map(i => i + 9)
const down = [...Array(4).keys()].map(i => 9 - i).reverse()
const result = [...new Set([...down, ...up])]
```

But if `n` is changed to `1` I only want to return the positives. How do I do that without a bunch of `if` statements? And is there are more efficient way to write this? It's for a paginator if you can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out values that go beyond the minimum and maximum page numbers. Putting it into a function for convenience:

```js
const paginate = function(num, pages, min, max) {
  const up = [...Array(pages - 1).keys()].map(i => num + i + 1).filter(i => i <= max);
  const down = [...Array(pages - 1).keys()].reverse().map(i => num - i - 1).filter(i => i >= min);
  return [...down, num, ...up];
}

console.log(paginate(5, 4, 1, 10));
console.log(paginate(9, 4, 1, 10));
console.log(paginate(1, 4, 1, 10));
```

This can be simplified to:

```js
const paginate = (num, pages, min, max) =>
  [...Array(pages * 2 - 1).keys()].map(i => num + 1 - pages + i).filter(i => i <= max && i >= min);

console.log(paginate(5, 4, 1, 10));
console.log(paginate(9, 4, 1, 10));
console.log(paginate(1, 4, 1, 10));
```

Comment: Out of preference this one reads as clearest I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution that's a bit more consolidated.

```js
const pager = (current) => [...Array(7).keys()]
  .map(el => el - 3 + current)
  .filter(el => el > 0);
  
  console.log(pager(1));
  console.log(pager(4));
  console.log(pager(8));
  console.log(pager(15));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would've taken a different approach where you loop through the values. No need to keep on deconstructing an array.

```
const spread = (num, range, max=100) => {
  let ary=[];
  for (let i=num-range; i<num+range+1; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i < max) ary.push(i);
  }
  return ary;
}

console.log(spread(9, 3));
// [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

console.log(spread(1, 3));
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.filter` (which creates yet another new array) is not necessary. For example:

```js
function foo(n) { // n must be >= -3
  return n>3 ? [...Array(7).keys()].map(x => x + n - 3) : [...Array(3+n).keys()].map(x => x + 1)
}

console.log(foo(-3))
console.log(foo(-2))
console.log(foo(-1))
console.log(foo(0))
console.log(foo(1))
console.log(foo(2))
console.log(foo(3))
console.log(foo(4))
console.log(foo(9))
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is this:

```
[...result].filter(i => i > 0)
```

Works well enough, although this will need upper-range filtering too for the pagination, but another filter like `.filter(i => i < this.totalPages)` or whatever will work.